# Raspbian echo device

Tags: echo, raspbian, tty

I need to create an echo device for software tests under Raspbian.

The aim is a device, that returns everything. E.g. if I would send some data to a device (`ls > /dev/tty30`), I need this data back from this (or an equal) device.

Is there already a possibility out-of-the-shelf inside Raspian? (e.g. an echo device)
Can I create such a device by an serial null modem simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspbian sure supports such behaviour:

```
root@raspberrypi:/root# mkfifo /dev/tty100
root@raspberrypi:/root# cat < /dev/tty100 |cat > /dev/tty100&
[1] 19024
root@raspberrypi:/root# echo hi > /dev/tty100
root@raspberrypi:/root# cat /dev/tty100
hi
^C
```

Comment: In bash it works. But I can't open the device tty100 as a serial port via an application (or via "screen /dev/tty100"). Is there a change to open tty100 via an application?

Comment: You can find failed ioctls/opens/whatever by running strace with your app. Ofcourse device pseudo-file handle differs from simple fifo. There is no echo kernel module which does this task. In the very worst case any decent developer can write ioctl-replacer which can be load on application startup through LD_PRELOAD variable. Your app will call some ioctl to determine device capabilities, pseudocode in preloaded library will reply with faked answer, the rest will be made by code described above.